# Rendering HTML using Gulp.js template compilers

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

What would be the easiest way to use any one of the Gulp template compilers to render HTML files?

```
gulp.task('html', function () {
  gulp.src('templates/**/*')
  .pipe(handlebars())
  .pipe(whatCanGoHereToRenderHTML())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('www'));
});
```

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32228623/1577396). might help you.

Comment: Or use https://github.com/skuligowski/gulp-htmlrender. It allows to create custom tags and also use can stream all your includes to change them before rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way I found to render templates directly to HTML is by using the [gulp-consolidate](https://github.com/timrwood/gulp-consolidate) plugin as per the following example:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');
var consolidate = require('gulp-consolidate');


gulp.task('html', function() {
  gulp.src('templates/**/*.html')
    .pipe(consolidate('handlebars', {msg:'This is a message!'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('www'));
});
```

Keep in mind that the [handlebars](https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js) library would also need to be installed for this example to work.