# Create pages with pre-compiling the templates

Tags: javascript, html, css, templates

In my current project, my work is only with html and css (*HTML skinning*). There are many pages which have repeated sections like Header, footer, sharing links etc.

I don't want to repeat this common sections again and again in each page. I want these repeated sections to call somehow using gulp or any other task runner.

Something like this for example (*using lodash*)

#### Index.html

```
<!Doctype html>
<html>
    <%= _.template(templates['head'])() %>
    <body>
        <%= _.template(templates['header'])() %>

        <!-- some unique content here -->

        <%= _.template(templates['footer'])() %>
    </body>
</html>
```

and then using [gulp-template](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-template) rendering it in each page. I am preferring lodash because I had already worked with it.

As you can see, I am assuming that if somehow I keep the repeating sections in a javascript object (*with name `templates`*),  I can call it in one line code. And then if I change something in that repeating section, the change will occur in all pages.

To make this possible, first I need to generate the javascript object with that repeating html as string in it.

Can someone please tell me how to do this? or is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Jade](http://jade-lang.com/) - node template engine

It gives option to [include](http://jade-lang.com/reference/includes/) external jade files, where in it allows you to insert the contents of one jade file into another

#### index.jade:

```
doctype html
html
  include ./includes/head.jade
  body
    h1 My Site
    p Welcome to my super lame site.
    include ./includes/foot.jade
```

#### head.jade

```
//- includes/head.jade
  title My Site
  script(src='/javascripts/jquery.js')
  script(src='/javascripts/app.js')
```

#### foot.jade

```
//- includes/foot.jade
#footer
  p Copyright (c) foobar
```

### Compiles to:

#### index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My Site</title>
    <script src='/javascripts/jquery.js'></script>
    <script src='/javascripts/app.js'></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>My Site</h1>
    <p>Welcome to my super lame site.</p>
    <div id="footer">
      <p>Copyright (c) foobar</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Explanation:

Whenever I used to search on google for "pre-compiling templates", I was ending up on sites which were combining all the HTML template files to one single js file. But in my case, I was looking for a way to compile the templates completely on system itself with no support of a "all template compiled js file". (*So, I was looking for a solution which **pre-renders** the HTMLs*)

#### Solution:

I found this awesome template engine, [Nunjucks](http://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks/), which lets me compile the HTML templates to Independent HTML pages when used with gulp.

Check this one, [gulp-nunjucks-render](https://github.com/carlosl/gulp-nunjucks-render). By using this along with gulp, I am able to include section of `.html` files into other `.html` files. Here is the code (*assuming you installed nodejs and gulp*):

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var nunjucksRender = require('gulp-nunjucks-render');

gulp.task('default', function () {
    nunjucksRender.nunjucks.configure(['templates/'], { watch: false });
    return gulp.src('templates/!(_)*.html')
        .pipe(nunjucksRender({
            css_path: "../assets/css/",
            js_path: "../assets/js/",
            img_path: "../assets/images/"
        }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('html'));
});
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    gulp.watch(['templates/*.html'], ['default']);
});
```

In the above code, I am keeping the HTML templates in `templates` folder and with the above gulp code, I am generating the new HTMLs in `html` folder. The above code will not generate the files which are prefixed with `_`. (*something similar to sass*)

and later in command prompt:

```
gulp watch  // Watches the files for changes continuously --> OWNING :D
```

Here is an example:

```
<!-- // Index.html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    {% include "_head.html" %}
    <body>
        {% include "_content.html" %}
        {% include "_footer.html" %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Which renders to:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Website title</title>
        <link rel="Stylesheet" href="../assets/jcss/main.css" type="text/css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="page">
            <!-- content here -->
        </div>
        <div class="footer">
            <!-- footer content here -->
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

#### Advantages:

- No need of server support to compile the templates.
- No need to include any pre-compiled js file in index.html.
- Whenever we do some change in common section, no need to include that section again in every page.

#### Disadvantages:

- Till now, I didn't find any :).