# Automatically embed a stylesheet in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css, build, gulp

I'm building out error pages (404/503) which need to be standalone html files, my server-side is nodejs, but these files will be hosted directly in nginx. I'm trying to automatically *embed* a stylesheet at the top of a html document and was wondering whether there are any tools for this purpose.  Searching on stack overflow and google keeps returning tools to inline css for use in emails, but that is not what I want.

I would like to start out with

### before.css

```
.body { color: black }
```

### before.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>A Question</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="before.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Here be the answer</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Which once the process is complete I would end up with

### after.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>A Question</title>
    <style>.body { color: black }</style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <p>Here be the answer</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

The ideal solution would be a gulp plugin or an idea of how to write one.
I can write this in JS if needed. Also I'm already using EJS and Stylus to derive the original before files.

Many thanks

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What server language are you using?

Comment: If you don't find an easy way to do that... mainly it's because it's a bad idea or you are making a great innovation...

Why do you want to do this ?

Comment: You seems to be looking for HTML pre-compilation tools. there are many. look in jade or Haml. Here is a [**related post**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31355778/1577396).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As many commented, you're trying to find a solution to a very complex problem and there are probably many easy to use workarounds for this. But if you really want to do this then here are a few approaches I think best:

### Server-side Templates:

The best, clean and straightforward method of embedding a stylesheet into HTML is to use a server-side scripting language (as @Mr_Green pointed out). There are many to chose from, and as you're using Node.js, the best library would be EJS or Jade. You can also use PHP, Ruby, Python or whatever you think best, but the idea is same:

1. **First**, you need to read the contents from the stylesheet and store it in a variable. In Node.js you can use the `fs.readFile()` to easily read the contents of the .css file.
2. **Then**, you have to output the contents of the .css file (stored in a variable) into your HTML. With EJS for example, if the contents of your CSS file is in a variable `styleFile`, then you can do `<style><%= styleFile %></style>` to directly put the contents of your stylesheet into your HTML `<style>` tag.

### Using Ajax with JavaScript:

Another solution would be to use Ajax and get the contents of your stylesheet and then use JavaScript to simply put it inside your `<style>` tag. For example with some jQuery you could do: `$("style").html(// stylesheet contents var);`.

Of course you can also use **Haml**, if that helps.

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer @Abraar-Arique. Your answer got me thinking in the right direction.